# What to make out of fire in Home's temple?

Tags: belief, temple, guru, omens

Fire in temple room in home(not the temple itself). It burned the photo of Neeb Karoli Baba that my mother reveres completely. Fortunately the temple itself was left unscathed. Should I make it out to be something bad like bad energy or bad omen?

Comment: Just take care that the flame of lit dīpa (or its battī), lit kapūra, lit agarabattīs or lit dhūpa is sufficiently away from wood, cloth, paper, etc. and other objects that can burn upon contact with fire. The lit items should be so far, that even if there's wind or they are to extinguish, they (or their fiery part) doesn't touch other objects which can burn upon contact with flame. Also, burnt matchsticks should be properly extinguished before throwing them anywhere. If this little care is taken, the possibility of accidental burning of things in one's temple at home, would be extremely low.